# Swift get volume of device without disrupting current playback

Tags: swift

I want to get the current output volume of a device. I have been searching around for a very long time and I know there are various threads about this topic but I really could not find a way to keep the playback going when reading the volume.
The most things I found were something like this:

```swift
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var volume: Float?
do {
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
    volume = audioSession.outputVolume
} catch {
    print("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
}
```

But by setting the `active` parameter to true it seems that every other output is just canceled.

Is there a way to get the volume without the described side effect?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by setting the playback option to be `mixWithOthers`. I assume that means, that it accepts simultaneously playback. Here is the function to get the volume without disrupting the current playback:

```swift
func getVolume() -> Float {
   do {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
        try session.setActive(true)
        return session.outputVolume
   } catch {
        print(error)
        return 0
   }
}
```